# Clipping vector layers with different CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, clip, distortion

I have two vector layers:

1. provinces (Belge_Lambert_1972, EPSG:103300) - clip layer
2. building (WGS 84/ Pseudo Mercator, EPSG:3857) - input layer

I would like to overlay them, however there is something wrong. I believe it had to do with the Coordinate Reference System.

When i work with the layer without conversion of the reference systems, the data does overlay exactly. I know that the buildings should lie within the provinces from the definition of the layer. However, when I want to clip the layers I get an notification:

> Layers do not all use the same CRS. This can cause unexpected results.
>   Do you want to continue?

[image]

On the other hand, when I do convert the *WGS 84/ Pseudo Mercator, EPSG:3857* to *Belge_Lambert_1972, EPSG:103300* CRS, the layers are not overlapping at all. Actually, I can find the layers by using "zoom to layers".

**How can I clip these two layers correctly?**

Comment: I guess you just tried to right-click "set layer crs", you should "save as" and choose the projection, layer will upload in the layers panel, then you do the clip

Comment: I had exaclty the same problem and unfortunately the solution is not working for me. When I try to save as esri shapefile with the new solution there is an error saying "OGR error:Failed to create file n.shp: Permission denied). What else can I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eliot has right.  You might perform a projection instead of reprojection.

Your data were created in differents CRS, that's mean that coordinates of your geometries are not the same but with OFP (on flight projection) you visualize your data as there were convert on the defined CRS in your projet.  But to perform analyses or spatial algorithms, the geometries of  your two differents  dataset need to fit each other .
To do so you should use the Save As layer  option  (right click on the layer in layer panel).

If you use set layer CRS instead of converting,  the coordinates of your geometry will not change. Than with Save as,  coordinates are converted under the new CRS.